# TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars when basic operations are used

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to write the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def duplicate(im):
    img1 = im.copy()
    k = im.shape
    i=1
    x=k[0]
    y=k[1]
    while(i<(x-2)):
        j=1
        while(j<(y-2)):
            print i,j
            a = (int(im[i,j+1])-int(im[i,j]))
            b = (int(im[i+1,j])-int(im[i,j]))
            c = (a**2) + (b**2)
            c = np.sqrt(c)
            if(c>=40):
                img1[i,j] = img1[i-1,j] = img1[i,j-1] = img1[i-1,j-1] = 255
            else:
                img1[i,j] = 0
            j+=1
        i+=1
    return img1
im = cv2.imread('book013.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,50,255,0)
img1 = duplicate(im)
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img1,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
#print contours[42]
l=len(contours)
i=0
rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[l-1])
box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
box = np.int0(box)
image1 = cv2.drawContours(im,[box],0,(0,0,255),2)
while(i<l):
    print contours[i]
    print cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
    i+=1
#area = cv2.contourArea(contours)
#print area
#cv2.imwrite('bookd013.png',image)
cv2.imshow('image',image1)
#cv2.imshow('image'image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

It is showing an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Python\test15.py", line 30, in <module>
    img1 = duplicate(im)
  File "C:\Python27\Python\test15.py", line 14, in duplicate
    a = (int(im[i,j+1])-int(im[i,j]))
 TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Can anyone suggest what changes could be made to this code?

Comment: What do you expect `int(im[i,j+1])` to do? Particularly, what do you expect `im[i,j+1]` to be?

Comment: Actually, both im[i,j+1] and int(im[i,j+1]) are same. But when I used im[i,j+1] instead of int(im[i,j+1]), it gave several warnings.

Comment: "Actually, both im[i,j+1] and int(im[i,j+1]) are same" - no they're not. Did you mean to work with `imgray` instead of `im`? Also, you should probably read about `for` loops, because the way you're writing your loops is messy and error-prone.

Comment: Oh thanks. I forgot to convert im to imgray.I understood the problem.